# Dependency Property binding not being updated

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I have defined a dependency propery as follows:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AnimateColumnWidthProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("AnimateColumnWidthProperty", typeof(double), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));

public double AnimateColumnWidth
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(AnimateColumnWidthProperty); }
    set { SetValue(AnimateColumnWidthProperty, value); }
}
```

When my application starts I do this....

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AnimateColumnWidth = Properties.Settings.Default.ProductInfoWidthExpanded;
}
```

... which should initialise the value to its starting value - in this case 400.

I have then bound a column of a grid in my UI to this property...

```
<ColumnDefinition 
    Name="ProductInfo" 
    Width="{Binding Path=AnimateColumnWidth,
                    Converter={StaticResource doubleToGridLength},
                    Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

As I understand it, as the column width is bound to this property, whenever I update the property the column width should also update.

What am I doing wrong as the width does not update when I change the property? I am also trying to update it via an animation which also doesnt work. Additionally, a breakpoint set on the getter of the AnimateColumnWidth property is never hit - meaning that nothing ever tried to retrieve the property.

(This did work so clearly I have broken something somewhere!!)

Footnote:

The value converted is defined in the root namespace of my app (I believe that WPF would complain if it couldnt find it).

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(Double), typeof(GridLength))]
public class DoubleToGridLength : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new GridLength((double)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((GridLength)value).Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I hadnt done was set the datacontext of the grid who's column I wanted to affect to "this".

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ProductsArea.DataContext = this;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You register the property as `"AnimateColumnWidthProperty"`, which is "wrong", only the field name is arbitrary, you probably want `"AnimateColumnWidth"` (or you change the binding of course, but as is, it fails since the path points to an unregistered property).

You might want to read something on debugging [bindings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx) as well, then you can spot such errors as they will be reported by the binding engine. (something like "property x not found on object y").

Also using breakpoints in the getters or setters does not tell you anything, the binding engine does *not* use them, they are just for your own convenience.

Comment: The hint on bindings did the trick. The datacontext of the grid had not been set.